# Encoding HTML for input

Tags: html, forms, razor, webmatrix

I have created a form for customers to request information from a site. The form then sends me an email using Webmail.Send. The site will throw an error if the user tries to input part or all of an html opening tag, ie "<h1" or "<h1>". I developed the site with WebMatrix and I am trying to solve this issue using Html.Encode(). If I hard code in Html.Encode("<h1>") everything is great, the email is sent and the html tag looks great in the email. If I try to use a variable, Html.Encode(firstName), the site crashes if the user enters part or all of an html opening tag. If the user enters something that doesn't look like html then everything is fine, ie "Steve". Below is the code I am having issues with.

```
    var customerEmail = Request["customerEmail"];
    var firstName = Request["firstName"];
    var lastName = Request["lastName"];
    var phoneNumber = Request["phoneNumber"];
    var customerRequest = Request["customerRequest"];
    var rAddress = Request["rAddress"];
    var rCity = Request["rCity"];
    var rState = Request["rState"];
    var rZip = Request["rZip"];

    try
        {
            WebMail.Send(to:"request@yourdomain.com", subject: "Request from " + customerEmail, body: 
            "Request:<br>_____________________________________<br><br>" +
            customerRequest + "<br><br>Contact Info:<br>_____________________________________<br><br>" + Html.Encode(firstName)  + " " + lastName + "<br>" + rAddress + 
            "<br>" + rCity + " " + rState + " " + rZip + "<br>" + phoneNumber + "<br>" + customerEmail, replyTo: customerEmail);
        }
    catch (Exception ex )
        {
            <text>@ex</text>
        }
```

I know the issue is possible with all of the inputs but that will be easily fixed once I figure out this first one.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: This is the first part of it: [HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (firstName="<h1").]

Comment: The error is occurring when the variable “firstName” is being declared and set to the value from the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow users to post HTML as part of their form submission, you must use `Request.Unvalidated()` to reference the form field value to prevent ASP.NET request validation from kicking in (which results in the error message you reported):

```
var firstName = Request.Unvalidated("firstName");
var lastName = Request.Unvalidated("lastName");
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that did it! I added to it make any HTML or HTML "like" characters come through.

Comment: var firstName = Html.Encode(Request.Unvalidated("firstName"))